# creating nodes in xml never close

Tags: php, xml

Im trying to create an file that looks like this

```
<blogs>
<blog title="Ipsum" text="Ipsum">
<photo photos=img1"/>
<photo photos=img2"/>
<photo photos=img3"/>
</blog>
<blog title="ipsum2" text="ipsum2">
<photo <photo photos=img4"/>
```

but for some reason the output never close the nodes and shows the xml file like this

```
<blogs>
<blog title="Ipsum" text="Ipsum" />
<photo photos=img1"/>
<blog title="Ipsum" text="Ipsum"/>
<photo photos=img2"/>
<blog title="Ipsum" text="Ipsum"/>
<photo photos=img4"/>
<blog title="ipsum2" text="ipsum2"/>
<photo photos=img4"/>
</blogs>
```

this is my function.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$root = $dom->createElement("blogs");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($root);

$root = $dom->createElement("blog"); 
$newnode = $parnode->appendChild($root);   

 $photo = $dom->createElement("photo");
 $parnode->appendChild($photo);
 $newnode->setAttribute("title",$row['title']);
 $newnode->setAttribute("text", $row['text']);  
 $photo->setAttribute("photos", $row['photos']); 

  echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: I don't understand your intention. can you please provide more info? does blog and photo should be associated?

Comment: @Swamy yes, im adding images to the text, so every text could have more than one 1 image.

Comment: @Dymond: Check `$parnode` here. Is it the right parent?

Comment: Also: What is your concrete programming questions. Just dropping requirements and a silly "any ideas?" is not really worth on a Q&A page about programming questions. Or shorter: One idea I have is programming this. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are appending `photo` elements to root `blogs` insetead of `blog` element

Try this code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$root = $dom->createElement("blogs");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($root);

$root = $dom->createElement("blog"); 
$newnode = $parnode->appendChild($root);   

 $photo = $dom->createElement("photo");
 $newnode->appendChild($photo); // HERE you need change $parnode to $newnode
 $newnode->setAttribute("title",$row['title']);
 $newnode->setAttribute("text", $row['text']);  
 $photo->setAttribute("photos", $row['photos']); 

  echo $dom->saveXML();
```

---

Additional example with loops for 10 blogs with 10 photos:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$root = $dom->createElement("blogs");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($root);
for($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++){
    $root = $dom->createElement("blog");
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($root);

    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
        $photo = $dom->createElement("photo");
        $newnode->appendChild($photo);
        $newnode->setAttribute("title",$row['title']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("text", $row['text']);
        $photo->setAttribute("photos", $row['photos']);
    }
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: No it actually close the the blog node, but the photo is still creating  new blog nodes and not like
<blogs>
<blog>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
</blog>
</blogs>

more like this
<blogs>
<blog>
<photo></photo>
</blog>
<blog>
<photo></photo>
</blog>
</blogs>

Comment: If you want more `photo` elements in one `blog` element just put them in it, in the sample you gave you have only one photo in one blog.

Comment: @Dymond I added additional example for multiple photos in multiple blogs, hope it helps.

Comment: yes! that was exactly what i was trying to archive. thank you so much. you are a ninja.